# SQL syntax error or missing database (near "(": syntax error) when using union

Tags: sqlite, syntax, union

I am trying to use union but i get this vague syntax error. I Can get each query to run seperately, but when i try to use union i get this error.

```
(SELECT s.sname, COUNT(s.sname) AS number
FROM sailor s, boat b
WHERE  b.rating <= s.rating
GROUP BY s.sname)
UNION
(SELECT s.sname, 0 AS number
FROM sailor s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
              SELECT * FROM boat b
              WHERE s.rating >= b.rating));
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, only subqueries use parentheses. In a compound query, the individual SELECTs must be written without them:

```
SELECT s.sname, COUNT(s.sname) AS number
FROM sailor s, boat b
WHERE  b.rating <= s.rating
GROUP BY s.sname
UNION
SELECT s.sname, 0 AS number
FROM sailor s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
              SELECT * FROM boat b
              WHERE s.rating >= b.rating);
```

---

And in this specific case, you might just want to use an [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join):

```
SELECT s.sname,
       IFNULL(COUNT(b.rating), 0) AS number
FROM sailor AS s
LEFT JOIN boat AS b
ON b.rating <= s.rating;
```